# cannot view arbic text with ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, xml

i try to  showing the Arabic text inside view pager but The text appears inexplicably I use the appropriate libraries and everything is good but 
I do not know why the text does not appear as usual , What can I do? 
What suggestions are appropriate ?
screen shot:

[image]

```
 //sample xml : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        tools:context=".SampleActivity">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <com.booking.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    // fragment_main xml : 

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="60dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    // SampleActivity class : 


    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;



    public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sample);
            TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            //TextViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TextViewPagerAdapter(7);
            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), new String[]{"الاحد ","الاثنين ","الثلاثاء ","الاربعاء"});
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }







        public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

            private String [] strings;
            public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm  , String []stringstodisplay) {
                super(fm);
                this.strings = stringstodisplay;
            }




            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int pos){
                return FragmentViewPager.newInstance(strings[pos]);
            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return strings.length;
            }
        }


        static class TextViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private int pages;


            TextViewPagerAdapter(int pages) {

                this.pages = pages;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return pages;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {

                // Text Page
                final String item = "" + position;
                final TextView text = new TextView(container.getContext());
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                text.setTextSize(30);
                text.setText(item);
                container.addView(text, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
                text.setTag(item);
                return item;
            }



            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {


                return String.valueOf(position);
            }



            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return object.equals(view.getTag());
            }


            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {


                container.removeView(container.findViewWithTag(object));
            }


            // End  -------------- ;

        }
    }

    // FragmentViewPager class : 

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    public class FragmentViewPager extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

        // ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tv.setText(getArguments().getString("text"));
            //tv.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            //imageView.setBackgroundResource(getArguments().getInt("img"));
            return v;
        }



        public static FragmentViewPager newInstance(String text) {
            FragmentViewPager f = new FragmentViewPager();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("text", text);
           // b.putInt("img", image);
            f.setArguments(b);
            return f;
        }
    }
```